# How to get the 4*4 matrix from the twist using product of exponentials, in robot kinematics?

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, forward-kinematics, product-of-exponentials, screw-theory

In robot kinematics, we have $e^{(\theta*twist)}$, where $twist$ is 6*1 vector.  How do I get the 4 by 4 transformation matrix by using product of exponentials?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the 6x1 vector is sometimes better referred to as the coordinates of the twist. The twist itself is a 4x4 matrix, element of $SE(3)$, found by
$$
\begin{align}
A &= \begin{bmatrix} \widehat{\omega} & v \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\\
v &\triangleq -\omega \times q
\end{align}
$$
where $\omega$ is the unit vector pointing along the axis of rotation (for a rotating joint), $\widehat{\omega}$ is the 3x3 skew symmetric matrix derived from $\omega$, and $q$ is any point along the axis of rotation. The matrix exponential is then found by
$$
\begin{align}
e^{A \theta} &= \begin{bmatrix}
R & (I-R)(\omega \times v) + \omega \omega^T v \theta \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\
R &= e^{\hat{\omega} \theta} = I + \hat{\omega} \sin\theta + \hat{\omega}^2 (1-\cos\theta)
\end{align}
$$

For a more detailed explanation, see section 3.2 of [Murray, Li, and Sastry](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/mlswiki/index.php/First_edition).